# jqgrid - sort jqgrid together with json data

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid. I need to pull the json data from jqgrid after the client sorted the grid. Pulled json data should be the sorted version and not the original. How can I do this?

Here is my jqgrid source

```
jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    datastr: jsonData,
    datatype: 'jsonstring',
    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, root: function(obj) { return obj; }},
    colNames: [ 'Column 1',
                'Column 2'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'prop1',    index: 'prop1'},
        { name: 'prop2',    index: 'prop2'},

    ],
    headertitles: true,
    sortable: true,
    pginput: true,
    rownumbers: true,
    rowNum: 5,
    rowList: [5,20, 100, 10000],
    pager: '#pager',
    width:'600',
    height:'300',
    shrinkToFit:false,
    viewrecords: true,
    loadonce: true
});
```

Currently when I `alert(jsonData)` in the gridComplete it shows the original json data and not the sorted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who come across this problem, you can just take the `data` parameter passed to the `loadComplete` event of jqGrid. This data is the sorted version of the grid's data source.